# SQL: Sum a negative and positive real gives wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

Why does the following query result in the value  `3.21865081787109E-06` when the value should be zero?

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST
GO
USE TEST
CREATE TABLE NUMS (NUMBER REAL)
GO
INSERT INTO NUMS VALUES (1.67460317460317),(-1.6746)
GO
```

Then run:

```
SELECT SUM(NUMBER) FROM NUMS
```

This returns the value `3.21865081787109E-06`?

If I cast the values as decimal, or if I shorten the first number to `1.6746` it returns the correct value of zero?

**Also:** Summing the numbers manually gives the correct value, it looks as if `SUM()` trims the zeroes?

`select (1.67460317460317 + -1.6746)`

Returns:

`0.00000317460317`

Thank You!

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should it be 0?

```
   1.67460317460317
+ -1.6746
-------------------
=  0.00000317460317
=  3.17e-06
```

and the difference between your 3.21 and the "real" math 3.17 is just floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: I think the OP simply got confused by the `E-` notation, and thought the value was more than three.

Comment: That, im ashamed to say, I did!